# If you "buy" an app in the Amazon Underground, and it is later removed from the Underground, do you get to keep it?

Tags: applications, paid-apps, amazon-appstore, in-app-purchase, amazon-underground

If you aren't familiar, the Amazon Underground offers a bunch of apps for free (including IAPs).  The downsides are user tracking, pop-over ads, and the possibility of the app not working if there is no internet connection.

Once a person "buys" an app in the Amazon Underground, it is listed in the associated Amazon account.  (I put "buys" in parenthesis because there is no charge.)

If the app is later removed from the Amazon Underground, does the "buyer" get to keep it?

Comment: I'm bit unclear here. Are you asking: If an app is removed from Amazon Underground, would its users lose the app automatically (removal triggers whenever Android sync with Amazon's server) OR is it legal for users to keep such an app after Amazon has it removed from Underground? The latter would be considered off-topic (we don't deal with legal questions. Visit [help/on-topic] for more info). However, this may help you a bit: https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/legal/da#AmazonUndergroundSchedule (see "**6. Withdrawal from Amazon Underground.**")

Comment: @Firelord I am just interested in the former (would users lose the app automatically).  I didn't even think of the legal side, as I would assume Amazon would immediately remove the app if there are any legal issues.  Regardless, as you mentioned, that is off-topic on this site, so we can't discuss it.

Comment: @Firelord The answer is *partially* in the latter link you provided: *"[Amazon] may continue to provide existing end users with access to all Amazon Underground Apps they purchased through Amazon Underground, along with any In-App Products they purchased through those Amazon Underground Apps, after those Amazon Underground Apps cease to be available for purchase through Amazon Underground."*  What that doesn't say is whether or not they typically perform that action.  Perhaps others know from experience.